# Browsers aborting AJAX requests

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-chrome, firefox

I have an application that is very data hungry, and has a variety of modules that require constant updates via AJAX requests. These can be bursts of 5 to 10 requests at a time (each module is on its own timer, sometimes they line up). Over a long period of time, usually 30+ mins, I will see one or two AJAX requests being aborted by the browser (chrome and FF, no IE support required for me). I know this to be true as Wireshark reveals that the browser is aborting the request.

I have created an AJAX queue that would limit to 5 concurrent requests at a time, as FF and Chrome state they can support 6. I don't know what my webserver is capable of (embedded system web server, not standard) but again it doesn't seem like the webserver even has a chance to respond. Over many hours, there will be dozens of aborted requests.

I want to prevent this and I can't think of what to do. Do I need to limit to one request at a time and wait till it is done?

Code:
This is how I am listening to request statuses. Hopefully this is not messing with anything.

```
/**
 * Set the global Ajax timeout
 */
$.ajaxSetup({
    timeout: 30000
});

/**
 * watch for any failed Ajax requests.
 */
(function(open) {
    XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open = function() {
        // Occurs on errors
        this.addEventListener("error", function() {
            console.error("XMLHttpRequest.open: Request error.");
            self.incrementFailure();
        }, false);
        // Occurs on aborts
        this.addEventListener("abort", function() {
            console.error("XMLHttpRequest.open: Request aborted.");
            self.incrementFailure();
        }, false);
        // Occurs on timeouts
        this.addEventListener("abort", function() {
            console.error("XMLHttpRequest.open: Request timed out.");
            self.incrementFailure();
        }, false);
        open.apply(this, arguments);
    }
})(XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open);
```

There's not much point to provide my queue.. this problem occurred before my queue, which I created to try and solve it.

Nothing special about how I do my requests. Intervals like

```
function getModuleData(myFile, params) {
    return $.get(myFile, params);
}

var module1 = setInterval(getModuleData.bind(this, 'file1.xml', {}), 5000);
var module2 = setInterval(getModuleData.bind(this, 'file2.xml', {}), 5000);
var module3 = setInterval(getModuleData.bind(this, 'file3.xml', {}), 5000);
```

Comment: Have you got any code so we can evaluate it?

Comment: Browser's don't spontaneously `abort` AJAX requests on their own. Is it possible you are aborting them and don't understand why? Browser's request limit already has a queue (I believe it's 6 concurrent, but it might be 8) so it will automatically queue your requests up after that, you don't need to handle it

Comment: I don't see any way I am purposefully aborting a request.. I just create a bunch of intervals to get some data, nothing more. Every now and then, these fail instantly, ie the webserver never gets the requests. I know this because I can use a debugger on the webserver and it never gets the requests, it is prematurely aborted.... The other interesting thing is, it will often be the same file many times in a row, then go back to normal. Then another file will be aborted a few times in a row..